# how to install mongodb specific version?

Tags: mongodb, installation

hi i want to install mongodb version 3.6.8 in my computer i follow mongodb official documentary but i got a error

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.6.8 mongodb-org-server=3.6.8 mongodb-org-shell=3.6.8 mongodb-org-mongos=3.6.8 mongodb-org-tools=3.6.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
mongodb-org-tools : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Stupid question: why do you want to install a 5 years old release which is officially "End of Life" since April 2021?

Comment: Sorry for that but i install latest version of mongodb in my system but  it can't support in my system that the reason i want to install lower version of mongodb